# Infinitesimal generator of Time dependent process

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stopping-times, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the infinitesimal generator of this process

$dY_{t}=\dfrac{b-Y_{t}}{1-t}dt+dB_{t}$ $0\leq a <1$, $Y_{0}=a$

where $B_{t}$ is a Brownian motion;
and I've found the solution:

$Y_{t}=a(t-1)+bt+(1-t)\int_{0}^{t}\dfrac{dB_{s}}{1-s}$

but I don't know how to find the infinitesimal generator because it's not homogeneous.

Can you help me please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is very similar to the usual one as explained here [Lecture 10: Forward and Backward equations for SDEs](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eholmes/teaching/asa19/handout_Lecture10_2019.pdf)

the generator is simply

$$\mathcal{L}f(x,t)=b(x,t)\cdot \nabla f(x,t)+\frac{1}{2}a(x,t)\nabla^2f(x,t),\text{ with } a(x,t):=\sigma(x,t)\sigma^{T}(x,t)$$

which follows by applying Itô's formula. So in the above case we have

$$\mathcal{L}f(x,t)=\frac{b-x}{1-t} f_{x}(x,t)+\frac{1}{2}f_{xx}(x,t).$$